# Play Json Parser: How to ignore field during json parser

Tags: json, scala, parsing, playframework, play-json

I am using Scala with play JSON library for parsing JSON. We are the facing the problem using JSON parsing is, we have same JSON structure, but some JSON files contain different with values structure with the same key name. Let's take an example:

**json-1**

```
{
  "id": "123456",
  "name": "james",
  "company": {
    "name": "knoldus"
  }
}
```

**json-2**

```
{
  "id": "123456",
  "name": "james",
  "company": [
    "knoldus"
  ]
}
```

**my case classes**

```
case class Company(name: String)
object Company{
  implicit val _ = Json.format[Company]
}

case class User(id: String, name: String, company: Company)
object User{
 implicit val _ = Json.format[Company]
}
```

while JSON contains company with JSON document, we are getting successfully parsing, but if company contains an array, we are getting parsing exception. Our requirements, are is there anyway, we can use play JSON library and ignore the fields if getting parsing error rather that, ignore whole JSON file. If I am getting, company array values, ignore company field and parse rest of them and map corresponding case class.

Answer (score 1):

I would do a pre-parse function that will rename the 'bad' company.

See the tutorial for inspiration: [Traversing-a-JsValue-structure](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJson#Traversing-a-JsValue-structure)

So your parsing will work, with this little change:

`case class User(id: String, name: String, company: Option[Company])`

The `company` needs to be an Option.

Comment: Hey @pme, in that case, our application is running fine, but our requirements are, if something happening bad with a company, ignore only company, but rest of the fields must be parsed. As per your solution, if we are getting, wrong company structure, our whole JSON will be ignore rather than only one field.

Answer (score -1):

Final we found the answer to resolving this issue, as we know, we have different company structure within JSON, so what we need to do, we need to declare `company` as a `JsValue` because in any case, whatever the company structure is, it is easily assigned to `JsValue` type. After that, our requirements are, we need to use object structure, and if `JSON` contains array structure, ignore it. After that, we used pattern matching with our company `JsValue` type and one basis of success and failure, we parse or `JSON.` The solution with code is given below:

```
case class Company(name: String)
object Company{
    implicit val _ = Json.format[Company]
}

case class User(id: String, name: String, company: JsValue)
object User{
    implicit val _ = Json.format[Company]
}

Json.parse("{ --- whatevery json--string --- }").validate[User].asOpt match {
    case Some(obj: JsObject) => obj.as[Company]
    case _ => Company("no-name")
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea. Consider the case where you have a database with a `Company` column; if you index on this column, you will have _a lot_ of `"no-name"` in the worst case. `Option[Company]` seems much more apprioriate.